# java IO symbols not recognized

Tags: windows

So I'm trying to learn Java and writing simple codes through Sublime Text 2 which I compile and run on my windows cmd prompt (which I've added on to my path as well as Cygwin to get a Linux environment).  I've downloaded and added the Java JDK JRE 1.8.0_73 to my path as well.

However, when I compile my code, I get an error like this:

```
CourseGrade.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
            IO.output("Enter your exam grade: ");
            ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade  
CourseGrade.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            examScore = IO.inputDouble();
                        ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade
CourseGrade.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            IO.output("Enter your lab grade: ");
            ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade
CourseGrade.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
            labScore = IO.inputDouble();
                       ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade
CourseGrade.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            IO.output("Enter your homework grade: ");
            ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade
CourseGrade.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            hwScore = IO.inputDouble();
                      ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade
CourseGrade.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            IO.outputIn("Your final grade is " + finalGrade);
            ^
    symbol:   variable IO
    location: class CourseGrade
7 errors

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the java code I've written: 

public class CourseGrade
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int examWeight = 70;    //Percentage weight given to examination
        int labWeight = 20;     //Percentage weight given to lab work
        int hwWeight = 10;      //Percentage weight given to homework

        double examScore;       //Exam score given to student
        double labScore;        //Lab score given to student
        double hwScore;         //Homework score given to student
        double finalGrade;      //Final grade obtained by student

        IO.output("Enter your exam grade: ");
        examScore = IO.inputDouble();

        IO.output("Enter your lab grade: ");
        labScore = IO.inputDouble();

        IO.output("Enter your homework grade: ");
        hwScore = IO.inputDouble();

        //Compute final grade as the weighted sum of exam, lab, and
        //and homework scores
        examScore = examScore + (examWeight / 100.0);
        labScore = labScore + (labWeight / 100.0);
        hwScore = hwScore + (hwWeight / 100.0);
        finalGrade = examScore + labScore + hwScore;

        //Output the final grade
        IO.outputIn("Your final grade is " + finalGrade);
```

I would really appreciate someone's help to figuring out this problem

Comment: You need to import the `IO` class. Maybe that is something provided by this course. And do yourself a favour and get an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ. They have many helpful (almost essential, really) tools.

Comment: Yes, the online course I'm taking uses Blue J as its IDE.  I wanted to compile all my codes through my cmd prompt, but now I'm considering installing the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in package or class called "IO" (upper case).  It sounds like static methods in some class that you wrote (or got from your professor).

Q: Did you get a .java source file or .jar file with "IO"?  If it's a .jar file, did you include it in your `CLASSPATH`?

Q: Did you `import` whatever package "IO" belongs to?  Per your sample code, it doesn't look like you imported *anything*...

Comment: Before I typed in: import java.io*; but I had a problem with that as well.

Comment: "import.java.io" wouldn't have helped - because package "java.io" has no "IO.inputDouble()", nor "IO.output()", etc.  Q: WHERE DID YOU GET THESE NAMES FROM???  Again - it sounds suspiciously like you should probably have been given some .java source file named "IO.java"...

Comment: PS: My strong preference for IDE happens to be Eclipse - largely because Eclipse has such a large ecosystem, and I use it for so many completely different things.  But Eclipse isn't necessarily "easiest" for beginners - your best bet is to use whatever IDE your course recommends.  IMHO...

Comment: I apologize for the lateness, but to answer your question. I got "IO.input..." from the online course video that the instructor used.  Even when I used the IDE recommended by the course, it still wouldn't recognize the IO symbol.  So what I did is used "Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);" and changed my variables to "in".  I was able to run the program.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  So I guess it's a "bug" in the course ;)